# Bootstrap 3 sm vs xs - webstorm changes the break point?

Tags: jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm working on a responsive site, and as I'm adjusting the size in the browser (FF), I've noticed the page doesn't switch from `xs` to `sm` until `837px` wide. According to bootstrap, it should be 768px, so why does this happen?

The code in question:

```css
div {
  border: 1px solid black;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />


<div class="col-xs-2 col-sm-10">
  <p>some content</p>
</div>
```

I even tried this:

```
@media (max-width: 767px) {
  width: something to test with;
}
```

I am testing this with FireFox's Responsive Design View (ctrl + shift+ m). Does that affect it?

**Update:** I figured out why it was messing up... in my webstorm ide, I clicked "preview in FF" that comes up when you hover, taking me to "localhost:63342/app/index.html". Not sure why, but when I browse to the location using "file:///home/me/dev/app/index.html" it works. **Why?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your code snippet the change occurs correctly at exactly `768px` as it should.

If it doesn't for you, your browser has a problem. Try restarting it, disabling addons, etc. The problem does not reside in the code of the page itself.

If the change happens correctly in your code snippet and not in your live page, it means there is some other CSS that overwrites Bootstrap's CSS. All you need to do is inspect the element at a browser width between 768px and 837px and see where the `width:16.66666667%;` is coming from.

Comment: Could the way I'm testing through  it off?

Comment: I always keep my inspector window on a separate screen, detached from the browser window. Even when I debug on one screen, I detach the inspector and stack it on half of the screen and put browser on the other half, but separated.

Comment: Tried that too... I am thinking its webstorm. I fixed it, but not sure how.

Comment: Before you do that, try inspecting in another browser. Maybe all you need to do is reinstall FF.